# Не могу понять поставленный вопрос о возвращаемом логическом значении

Tags: java, java-8

В кратцу суть задачи такова:

> • Если котик сыт (сытость больше нуля), то действие выполняется,
> например вывести соответствующую информацию в консоль.(действия:
> играл, спал, умывался и.т в это уже рандом делает) Показатель сытости
> при этом должен уменьшиться.
> •   Если котик голоден, то действие не
> выполняется (котик просит есть).
> •   Метод должен возвращать логическое
> значение, в зависимости от того было выполнено действие или нет.

Не понятна последняя часть. Не могу понять, что именно нужно возвратить. Как я понял нужно при условии false нужно покормить кота, путем подключения дополнительного метода eat(). Кстати про него говориться в задаче, но не знаю как это сделать.

```
boolean play() {
        if (satiety > 0) {
            System.out.println("играл");
            satiety--;
            return true;
        } else eat("Покорми котика");
        System.out.println("ел");
        return false;
    }
```

По условию задачи должны быть 3 метода eat()(перегруженные). Звучит это так: Сделать три перегрузки метода eat(), одна из них будет принимать только количество условных единиц сытости и увеличивать на них соответствующую переменную экземпляра, другая единицы сытости и название еды, третья не принимает параметров, но содержит внутри себя вызов перегрузки, принимающей единицы сытости и название еды.
Эту часть я сделал так:

```
void eat(String kol) {
        satiety += getSatiety();
    }

    void eat(int satiety, String foodName) {    
    }

    void eat() {
        eat(3, "Вискас");
    }
```

Comment: Вы сами не понимаете условие задачи

Comment: В этом то и дело, что не совсем понятно. Задачу реализовал, но без подключения метода eat(), но это не правильно.

Comment: Не реализовал, код совсем неправильный  и не полный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод должен возвращать логическое значение, в зависимости от того было выполнено действие или нет.

Вы должны из метода boolean возвращать true или false. Если действие выполнено, то true, если не выполнено, то false.

Можете объявить переменную и если событие случилось то присвоить ей true, в ином случае false и в конце вернуть.

Либо сразу при проверке выполнености действия делать return true или false.